# Compare names of two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select, where-clause

Hellow everyone. Here is my question. In the 1st table person name written in 2 languages in two columns. In the 2nd table column is one for name, so names are written either 1st language or 2nd language.

How to compare these two table? Does my code works?

```
... t.datebirth=p.datebirth and (t.name=p.name1 or t.name=p.name2)
```

Answer (score 1):

> `t.datebirth=p.datebirth and (t.name=p.name1 or t.name=p.name2)`
>
> Does my code works?

As I understood your question with the limited information you provided: yes, it works. It checks whether any of the two names in table `p` is equal to the name in table `t`.

You can simplify the logic with `in`:

```
t.datebirth = p.datebirth and t.name in (p.name1, p.name2)
```

This might not be a very efficient approach though. Depending on your use case, you might also want to consider two `left join`s, each joining on one of the names, and additional conditional logic in the rest of the query. But that cannot be assessed without a more detailed description of your use case.

Comment: Good solve. I try to use eft join as well. Thank you